# Create pdf from a variable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, jspdf

This question sounds repeated but I've never seen a condition likes mine :

I have a variable that contains html content as a string !

```
var toPrint = '<b>Hello world!</b>'
```

I want to get a pdf export from toPrint variable.

Here what I've done :

```
$('#printbutton').click(function () {   ///#printbutton is id of my button
var pdf = new jsPDF();
var toPrint = '<b>Hello world!</b>'
pdf.text(toPrint);
pdf.save('helloworld.pdf');
});
```

and the cdn I used :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
```

I want a pdf that recognize the tags and styles of my variable as html css and apply them to itself. is there any other cdn or options for this purpose ?

Even I use `fromHTML` function , it won't support UTF-8 characters . here's an example :

https://jsfiddle.net/f6nyrd3z/

Comment: You're using a pretty old version of jsPDF. Maybe a newer one could solve your problem ? Is that something you can change ?

Comment: I've tried many CDNs but none of them work for utf-8 characters and you're right this one that I used is super old .

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `pdf.text()` function which is designed to print text only. You'd better use the `pdf.fromHTML()` function which is designed to convert HTML tags into something nice.

Here is a small example : https://jsfiddle.net/v9d2er03/6/

Comment: appreciate your answer but looks like it doesn't support UTF-8 characters . if you have any suggestions for this issue , please update your answer.

Comment: Can you provide an example of string which is not working properly ?